# Screwed my online application (no cover letter by accident). Move on or contact HR?

Tags: resume, applications, cover-letter

I applied for a position (software engineer) through a company's JobScore portal and there was a checkbox to include a cover letter in raw text. I pasted a cover letter prepared beforehand and I submitted my application. At the very last second, I noticed that the checkbox was not ticked and thus no cover letter was attached to my application due to a bug in the interface (the cover letter textbox should only appear when the checkbox is ticked).

I just received an email saying that the recruitment team will not be moving forward with my application and I was wondering if it had to do with the lack of a covering letter. I really want the position and I believe my resume alone does no justice to my application. Should I move on or contact the HR department of the company?

Answer (score 6):

The cost/benefit analysis here is easy:

- If you do contact HR, you have a chance of getting the job.
- If you do not contact them, you will have no chance of getting the job.

The cost to you of contacting them is small - a few minutes of your time. The potential benefit is huge.

In other words - contact them. It can do no harm and possibly some good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jenny. I guess I just needed the encouragement as I thought HR wouldn't even bother reviewing my case.

Comment: There's no guarantee that they will, but I'd say it's definitely worth trying.

Comment: @Dennis: as Jenny said, technically you already *lost* the job.  So, making another stab at it isn't going to hurt anything.

Comment: The lack of covering letter probably didn't actually hurt you unless you were right on the edge as a marginal candidate... but as others said, there's nothing lost by resubmitting but printing and postage costs, and the extra effort (and willingness to admit and correct a mistake) just might catch someone's eye.